# In Krita, how to have contextual help?

Tags: krita

I am learning to use Krita, and I would like to have the contextual help turned on. This is sometimes called "hints", or "balloon help", and consists in small notes, containing some written help and/or descriptions, that pop-up next to a button, or other elements of the User Interface, when the mouse hovers on them.

Is this feature present at all in Krita?

And if it is, how can I activate it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to "tool tips" (or at least that's what Blender calls them), which are small text bubbles that pop up when you **keep your mouse hovered over an icon in Krita for about 2 seconds**. These are enabled by default and if do not pop up, then it may be a bug.

It is easier to hover over the icons with a computer mouse, rather than a tablet's pen.

The text often is just the name of the icon's tool and any associated hotkey for that in parentheses.

You can hover the tool icons, the brush presets, tool options like sliders, and more. Brush presets' and layers' tool tips display more information than just their name.

---

References

https://krita-artists.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-have-the-tools-come-up-with-their-label-when-you-hover-over-them/34159

https://krita-artists.org/t/tool-tips-mouseover-helptags-popups/24565/2

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/help.html